# Regex to get make summary of RSS feed item

Tags: html, regex, wordpress, rss

I'm needing a regex to strip HTML elements, and get the first 200 characters of an RSS feed item. It's through a wordpress plugin so I can't code PHP or anything and I need to try to do it in 1 regex command.

Comment: Can you post a sample of some sort? What kind of regex is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just getting the first 200 characters is something like this

```
^.{200}
```

Comment: This will only return the first 200 characters, not strip the HTML elements

Comment: @Malachi you are right, I read too quick. Then I need to wait for a sample of the data to update my answer